# Adding your API_KEY to an Android project downloaded from GitHub in the Gradle properties file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I am trying to add my `API_KEY` to a project downloaded from `GitHub`.  In the ReadMe of the project, it is asking for me to update the `gradle.properties` file, but I do not see any such file in the project.  I do see `local.properties` (which is where I presume I need to make the changes) and gradle-wrapper.properties file.  I have tried adding the `API_KEY` designation to each but neither seems to work.  I simply can get passed configure build step in Android Studio.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

The reason I presume that I update the `local.properties` is that it is not included in the build and therefore not exposing the `API_KEY` to anyone else.  Is this correct?

The log link takes me to the app/build.gradle file but i presume the `buildConfigField` should link to the actual `API_KEY` in some file but I am not sure where that exists?  Thanks in advance.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.70'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle- 
plugin:$kotlin_version"  

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

   allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gradle.properties` is not the same as `local.properties`. Create a file named `gradle.properties` in you `Project root folder` (outermost folder) and add the api key

```
API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you @nupadhyana.  That worked perfectly.  So let me ask you another question.  So I presume, I can add all types of relevant values to the build.properties file as well?  I am a [tag:Gradle] newb but will be taking a [tag:Gradle] course hopefully later this week.  Thanks again.

Comment: build.properties? You mean gradle.properties? yes you can